# Not able to break from loop while running a Telegram Bot

Tags: python, telegram, telegram-bot, py-telegram-bot-api

I am creating a Telegram Bot using [pyTelegramBotAPI](https://github.com/eternnoir/pyTelegramBotAPI) that sends real-time updates of ongoing cricket matches. I want to break the loop whenever the user enters the "/stop" command. I've looked up various sources and also tried several methods to achieve the same but all in vain. The loop continues to iterate. The closest I've reached is by exiting the program by raising an error. Also, while inside the loop, the getUpdates method always returns an empty list. I've also written an [issue](https://github.com/atishaye/TeleCrick/issues/1) for the same on GitHub.

```py
def loop(match_url):
    prev_info = ""
    flag = 1
    #continuously fetch data 
    while flag:
        response = requests.get(match_url)
        info = response.json()['score']
        #display only when the score updates 
        if str(info) != prev_info:
            prev_info = str(info)
            send_msg(info)
        else:
            pass
        send_msg(info)
        #this handler needs to be fixed 
        @bot.message_handler(commands=['stop', 'end'])
        def stop(message):
            #code to break the loop
            flag = 0
            return
```

Since this was not working, I willingly used this wrong method:

```py
while flag:
        response = requests.get(match_url)
        info = response.json()['score']
        if str(info) != prev_info:
            prev_info = str(info)
            send_msg(info)
        else:
            pass
        send_msg(info)
        @bot.message_handler(commands=['stop', 'end'])
        def stop(message):
            bot.polling.abort = True #an arbitrary function that raises error and exits the program
```

Here's the whole code. I've also added my GitHub [link](https://github.com/atishaye/TeleCrick) of this code:

```py
import requests, json, telebot

token = <TOKEN>
bot = telebot.TeleBot(token)

#parsing data from cricapi.com
def live_matches():
    #here I'm using the KEY obtained from cricapi.com
    curr_matches_url = "https://cricapi.com/api/cricket?apikey=<KEY>"  
    curr_matches = requests.get(curr_matches_url)
    match_data = curr_matches.json()['data']
    global unique_id_arr, score_arr
    unique_id_arr, score_arr = [], []
    match_details = ""
    for i in match_data:
        unique_id_arr.append(i["unique_id"])
    for i in range(len(match_data)):
        score_arr.append(match_data[i]["title"])
        score_arr[i] += "\n"
        match_details += str(i+1) + ". "
        match_details += score_arr[i]
    send_msg(match_details)

def send_msg(msg):
    url2 = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/sendMessage'
    data = {'chat_id': chat_id, 'text': msg}
    requests.post(url2, data).json()


@bot.message_handler(commands=['start', 'help'])
def send_welcome(message):
    bot.reply_to(message, "Howdy, how are you doing?")
    global chat_id
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    msg = bot.reply_to(message, "Welcome to test project\nEnter the match number whose updates you want to receive")
    live_matches()
    bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fetch_score)

def fetch_score(message):
    chat_id = message.chat.id
    match_no = message.text
    #checking if the number entered is present in the displayed list
    if not match_no.isdigit():
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, 'Error1!\nSelect a no. from the above list only')
        return bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fetch_score)
    elif 1 <= int(match_no) <= len(score_arr):
        unique_id = unique_id_arr[int(match_no)-1]
        global match_url
        #get the data of the desired match
        match_url = "https://cricapi.com/api/cricketScore?unique_id="+unique_id+"&apikey=<KEY>"
        loop(match_url)
    else:
        msg = bot.reply_to(message, "Error2!\nSelect a no. from the above list only")
        return bot.register_next_step_handler(msg, fetch_score)

def loop(match_url):
    prev_info = ""
    flag = 1
    #continuously fetch data
    while flag:
        response = requests.get(match_url)
        info = response.json()['score']
        #display only when the score updates
        if str(info) != prev_info:
            prev_info = str(info)
            send_msg(info)
        else:
            pass
        send_msg(info)
        #this handler needs to be fixed
        @bot.message_handler(commands=['stop', 'end'])
        def stop(message):
            #an arbitrary function that raises error and then exits
            bot.polling.abort = True 
bot.polling()
"""
#currently not using
def receive_msg():
    url1 = 'https://api.telegram.org/bot'+token+'/getUpdates'
    response = requests.get(url1)
    text = response.json()['result']
    if len(text) > 0:
        user_msg = text[-1]['message']['text']
        return user_msg
    return text
"""
```

Comment: Please show the complete code. Especially the '#code to break the loop' part

Comment: @0stone0 I've added both things. Please try again.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using `telebot`(pyTelegramBotAPI) package in the wrong way:

1. Why did you create your own function `send_msg` where there is already `send_message` method in `telebot` exists?
2. You are redeclaring your "stop" handler in the loop, which is wrong!

> My suggestion to you is to learn how to use the `pyTelegramBotAPI` properly!

Here is a demonstration code, that solves your problem:

```py
import telebot
from time import sleep

bot = telebot.TeleBot(BOT_TOKEN)
flag = 1

@bot.message_handler(commands=['loop'])
def loop(msg):
    while flag:
        bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, "ping")
        sleep(1)

@bot.message_handler(commands=['stop', 'end'])
def stop(msg):
    global flag
    flag = 0
    bot.send_message(msg.chat.id, "stopped")


bot.polling(none_stop=True)
```

Explanation:

- Declared `flag` as a global variable and set it to `1`
- "loop" handler for starting the loop that sends you "ping" message every second
- "stop" handler that changes `flag` to `0`, which terminates your running loop

Comment: Thank You very much @GooDeeJAY for your ans. This really helped me a lot. Regarding your first point, I'm well aware of that but I was just trying out some things. Other than that, I'll definitely look more into pyTelegramBotAPI.